# The deployment of manifest failed when I add Version Override 1.1

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am working a outlook Add In and want to implement SSO. Without SSO feature I was able to deploy the manifest.

When I add  tag in the code the deployment is failing.

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1">
  <WebApplicationInfo>
    <Id>....</Id>
    <Resource>api://....../access_as_user</Resource>
    <Scopes>
      <Scope>profile</Scope>
    </Scopes>
  </WebApplicationInfo>
</VersionOverrides>
```

Comment: For SSO, addin needs to be registered with Azure AD, refer to the documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2

Answer (score 1):

For SSO, addin needs to be registered with Azure AD, refer to the documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2